# Generating a Sphere

Tags: c++, c, opengl, geometry, opengl-3

I'am trying to draw a icosahedron using OpenGL 3.3+ so i may subdivided later on to make it a sphere, but I keep getting this error in VS2010 Express:

```
Stack around the variable '_vertices' was corrupted
```

Here is the code:

```
#include "Angel.h"

int CurrentWidth = 800,
CurrentHeight = 600,
WindowHandle = 0;

unsigned FrameCount = 0;
/*Default values used to draw the object*/
float X = 0.525731112119133606f;
float Z = 0.850650808352039932f;

GLuint
  VertexShaderId,
  FragmentShaderId,
  ProgramId,
  VaoId,
  VboId,
  ColorBufferId,
  IndexBufferId;

const GLchar* VertexShader =
{
  "#version 400\n"\

  "layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;\n"\
  "layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;\n"\
  "out vec4 ex_Color;\n"\

  "void main(void)\n"\
  "{\n"\
  " gl_Position = in_Position;\n"\
  " ex_Color = in_Color;\n"\
  "}\n"
 };

const GLchar* FragmentShader =
{
   "#version 400\n"\

   "in vec4 ex_Color;\n"\
   "out vec4 out_Color;\n"\

   "void main(void)\n"\
   "{\n"\
   " out_Color = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 );\n"\
   "}\n"
};

void InitWindow(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);

  glutInitContextVersion(4, 0);
  glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
  glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

  glutSetOption(
    GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,
    GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS
  );

  glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);

  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

  WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);

  if(WindowHandle < 1) {
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  glutReshapeFunc(ResizeFunction);
  glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);
  glutIdleFunc(IdleFunction);
  glutTimerFunc(0, TimerFunction, 0);
  glutCloseFunc(Cleanup);
}

void RenderFunction(void)
{
  ++FrameCount;

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 60, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)0);

  glutSwapBuffers();
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

void CreateVBO(void)
{
  /*Starting points*/
  GLfloat Vertices[][4] =
    {{-X,0.0f,Z, 1.0}, {X,0.0f,Z, 1.0}, {-X,0.0f,-Z, 1.0}, {X,0.0f,-Z, 1.0},
    {0.0f,Z,X, 1.0}, {0.0f,Z,-X, 1.0}, {0.0f,-Z,X, 1.0}, {0.0f,-Z,-X, 1.0},
    {Z,X,0.0f, 1.0}, {-Z,X,0.0f, 1.0}, {Z,-X,0.0f, 1.0}, {-Z,-X,0.0f, 1.0}};

  /*Incdices on how to draw the object using triangles*/
  GLubyte Indices[] =
    {1,4,0,     4,9,0,    4,5,9,    8,5,4,    1,8,4,
     1,10,8,    10,3,8,   8,3,5,    3,2,5,    3,7,2,
     3,10,7,    10,6,7,   6,11,7,   6,0,11,   6,1,0,
     10,1,6,    11,0,9,   2,11,9,   5,2,9,    11,2,7};

  /*Filling up the points which i need to draw from the start*/
  GLfloat _vertices[60];
  for (int i = 0; i < 60; ++i) {
      _vertices[(3*i)+0] = Vertices[Indices[i]][0];
      _vertices[(3*i)+1] = Vertices[Indices[i]][1];
      _vertices[(3*i)+2] = Vertices[Indices[i]][2];
  }
  /*End of nodes generation*/
  GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();<br/>
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &VaoId);
  glBindVertexArray(VaoId);<br/>
  glGenBuffers(1, &VboId);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VboId);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(_vertices), _vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

  glGenBuffers(1, &IndexBufferId);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBufferId);
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
  if(ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
  {
     exit(-1);
  }
}
```

Note: I only put the function of drawing and not everything,and that without using the Indices array it would draw some weird stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (int i = 0; i < 60; ++i) {`

should be

`for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {`

Otherwise, you're going out of bounds and modifying memory outside of the array, hence, the stack around the array is being corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing out of array bounds. `_vertices` is an array of 60 `GLfloat`s, but you're accessing it in the range `0 .. 3*59 + 2`.